# How to enter special characters in an EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there any way to input special characters (which are not present in the default soft keyboard ,eg. theta) in an Android EditText?

Thanks..

Comment: how many special characters are you looking to input. if they are only a handful, you could always make your own buttons for these characters and in the onClick, insert them into your EditText

Comment: From where you will get all the symbols? Because such symbols won't be present on default keyboard. You are suppose to add that symbols in your app and load it by casting implicilty.

Comment: @DrkStr basically i am trying to make an app for mathematical formulae. so there isnt a limit for symbols..

Comment: @GrIsHu i can save the necessary ones into a file (xml or text) and retrieve when necessary.. if there is a way to reconfigure the keyboard itself, that would be much better

Comment: @sisir: Well the question is how you will input those special characters? through custom keyboard or in some other way as default keyboard may not have those characters ?

Comment: @SpringBreaker custom keyboard is what will work best for me..but i dont know how to do it..

Comment: Have you looked at this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as per your need, I would like to suggest to create a custom keyboard because the stock keyboard which comes with the device may not have the special characters you need.

You can refer the following tutorial to create a custom keyboard

http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

or you can see this search result which may serve your purpose,

https://github.com/search?q=android+custom+keyboard&ref=cmdform

And from below site you can get the list of Unicode characters which Android supports,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

http://unicode-table.com/en/#0026

Note: *Writing the whole code to create a custom keyboard is beyond the scope of this answer, so I mentioned the reference link.*

Answer (score 1):

What you are going to do is to create a custom keyboard. First thing you want is to hide the default keyboard when an `EditText` is focused:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Now, you must create a custom layout (RelativeLayout or Multiple LinearLayouts this is your desire), create and set text to the buttons that you want to show. Make this keyboard view `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` or `setVisibility(View.GONE)`, and whenever your `EditText` is focused, make it `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

After keyboard is visible, programming the rest is up to you it is practically easy.

If you also need a guide, [here](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html) is an example.